# Null fields values when converting JSON string (no null values) to Google's OAuth API TokenResponse class

Tags: c#, json.net, google-oauth

My JSON string

```
{
  "AccessToken":"myAccessToken",
  "TokenType":"Bearer",
  "ExpiresInSeconds":"3600",
  "RefreshToken":"myRefreshToken",
  "Scope":"myScopes",
  "Issued":"05/07/2019 16:51:53",
  "IssuedUtc":"05/07/2019 14:51:53"
}
```

Object class that I'm using (Google APIs `TokenResponse` class)

```
public class TokenResponse
{
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
    public string TokenType { get; set; }
    public long? ExpiresInSeconds { get; set; }
    public string RefreshToken { get; set; }
    public string Scope { get; set; }
    public string IdToken { get; set; }
    public DateTime Issued { get; set; }
    public DateTime IssuedUtc { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using Json.NET to convert the JSON string into an object like this

```
string jsonToken = await System.IO.File.ReadAllTextAsync(pathJsonToken);
TokenResponse token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenResponse>(jsonToken);
```

`jsonToken` value is the JSON string I wrote above, when converting to `TokenResponse` only the fields `Issued`, `IssuedUtc` and `Scope` are populated.

At first I thought that the error was caused by the missing field `IdToken`, but I tried using a class defined by me, that is identical to Google's `TokenResponse`, and it passes all the values (except for `IdToken` obviously).

What I'm trying to do is to use the already existing class, but I can't make it work.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you trying to ignore your `IdToken` during seriaziation to JSON?

Comment: Yes, because I don't need it for my project, since there won't be more than 1 active Token simultaneously.

Comment: You can decorate `IdToken` with `[JsonIgnore]` annotation to ignore this property during serialization.

Comment: Have you tried using `JsonSetting()` property to ignore Null value i.e. new `JsonSerializer() {NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore };`

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar solution doesn't work as intended, fields I need are still null. I can't use RahulSharma solution because I can't edit the class I want to use.

Comment: @Adrian Well if you do not want to ignore the field, you can remove from the string like: `var json = JToken.Parse(jsonToken); json["IdToken"].Remove();` and then deserialize your string: `TokenResponse token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenResponse>(jsonToken); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TokenResponse` class you showed in your question works fine with the JSON you provided.  (Demo [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WRlAVh))

Now have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/Src/Support/Google.Apis.Auth/OAuth2/Responses/TokenResponse.cs) for Google's version of the same class.  Here is a stripped down version:

```
public class TokenResponse
{
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonPropertyAttribute("access_token")]
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
    
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonPropertyAttribute("token_type")]
    public string TokenType { get; set; }
    
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonPropertyAttribute("expires_in")]
    public Nullable<long> ExpiresInSeconds { get; set; }
    
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonPropertyAttribute("refresh_token")]
    public string RefreshToken { get; set; }
    
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonPropertyAttribute("scope")]
    public string Scope { get; set; }
    
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonPropertyAttribute("id_token")]
    public string IdToken { get; set; }
    
    [Obsolete("Use IssuedUtc instead")]
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonPropertyAttribute(Order = 1)] 
    public DateTime Issued
    {
        get { return IssuedUtc.ToLocalTime(); }
        set { IssuedUtc = value.ToUniversalTime(); }
    }
    
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonPropertyAttribute(Order = 2)]
    public DateTime IssuedUtc { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

It should be clear now what the problem is: their class is expecting different JSON property names than what you are using.  The JSON should look like this:

```
{
  "access_token": "myAccessToken",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": "3600",
  "refresh_token": "myRefreshToken",
  "scope": "myScopes",
  "Issued": "05/07/2019 16:51:53",
  "IssuedUtc": "05/07/2019 14:51:53"
}
```

This response format is well-documented in [section 5.1 of the OAuth 2.0 Spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-5.1) (RFC 6749).  But note that only the first five properties are defined by the spec; `Issued` and `IssuedUtc` appear to be extra properties added by Google (the former of which is marked obsolete in the code).

Here is a working demo using the correct JSON with Google's `TokenResponse` class:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/2wXojV

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, now I'm wondering why Google uses different names for naming their JSON fields and object properties.

Comment: The problem wasn't of Google but mine, since I was getting all the information about the Token (Fields name and values) from a query string and casting them directly to a string without creating the model first. Now it's all good and the JSON token string is all good.